# ExecuteRegisteredProxyOperation gives Exception "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object."

Tags: development

I've created a fulltrust proxy:

```
string assembly = "FullTrustProxyExecise1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=21621f0ea660fe24";
string type = "FullTrustProxyExecise1.WSCreatorProxy";
WSCreatorProxyArgs args = new WSCreatorProxyArgs();
args.Filename = filename;
args.Siteurl = siteurl;
string url=(string) SPUtility.ExecuteRegisteredProxyOperation(assembly, type, args);
return url;
```

This however gives an Exception:

"Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object."

I've checked with PowerShell if the proxy is available, it is.

Hints anyone ?

Comment: Am facing same issue, Have you got the solution, Please share me if you have.its very urgent for us. mkrishna.sp2010@gmail.com thanks,
Balaram

Comment: I'm having the same problem - were u able to resolve it?